# Trouble accessing selected value in Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, selectedvalue

I have assigned a list of class to listbox, and set it's Display and Value members

```
BTLtypeList.DataSource = InStore_operations.ActivationTypes;
BTLtypeList.DisplayMember = "Name";
BTLtypeList.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Then at some point I need to access selected value (ValueMember) of this ListBox. I expected it to work like this:

```
(byte)BTLtypeList.SelectedValue
```

but it shows me InvalidCastException (when, in debugger I move mouse over SelectedValue - I see that selected is ActivationType instance NOT it's Id value

then I tried it this way

```
((ActivationType)BTLtypeList.SelectedValue).Id
```

and again I get InvalidCastException (now debugger shows that SelectedValue is the desired Id value)

P.S. ActivationType is {byte Id, string Name}

**What could be the problem here?**

### EDIT

1) InvalidCastException message is "Specified cast is not valid"

2) Here goes the class definition although I guess there's no added value here:

```
public class ActivationType
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact message of `InvalidCastException` and also what is `ActivationTypes` ? Post the class definition. `ActivationType is {byte Id, string Name}` isn't helpful. Post the actual class definition.

Comment: Does `((ActivationType)BTLtypeList.SelectedItem).Id` work?

Comment: @chris actually it seems that SelectedItem is working... do you have idea why SelectedValue is not working?

Comment: Hard to tell. The code you posted looks fine. What's the result of `BTLtypeList.SelectedValue.GetType()`?

Comment: @chris when I load listbox items - i guess then SelectedIndexChanged is triggered for each item - then this GetType returns ActivationType, but after that it returns byte as it should..

Comment: Have you tried setting `ValueMember` _before_ setting `DataSource`?

Comment: @chris Thanks - settings ValueMember before setting did the trick! All the examples I have seen so far are with DataSource set first, so I hope there are no side-effects with this approach. P.S. If You will post Your suggestions as an answer - I will accept it. Thanks again for Your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

Setting `DataSource` *before* `ValueMember` will trigger `SelectedIndexChanged` before `ValueMember` was set. Until `ValueMember` is set to an actual member of the DataSource item type, `SelectedValue` will return the DataSource item object itself.

In other words, to fix this bug you simply have to change

```
BTLtypeList.DataSource = InStore_operations.ActivationTypes;
BTLtypeList.DisplayMember = "Name";
BTLtypeList.ValueMember = "Id";
```

to

```
BTLtypeList.DisplayMember = "Name";
BTLtypeList.ValueMember = "Id";
BTLtypeList.DataSource = InStore_operations.ActivationTypes;
```